# get the selected item in dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown; I need to get the value of selected item; but it keeps saying undefined;

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/pbe39/4/)
Am I doing something wrong?

```
<select class="ddl_status" id="status_ddl_20" style="display: none">
    <option value="Active">Active</option>
    <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
</select>

    $(document).on('change', '.ddl_status', function() {
    var parent= this.parent();
    alert((parent option:selected).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.value`

```
$(document).on('change', '.ddl_status', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

There is no need to get the parent element and find the selected option again - the selected options value becomes the `select` value.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny000/pbe39/1/)**

```
$(document).on('change', '.ddl_status', function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your fiddle was supposed to have something other than `display:none`?

Also, just use `$(this).val();` (Hint: `$` is jQuery)